# Why do I get a IllegalStateException when using scanner?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I keep getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException" after using Scanner()

this is what I have

```
public void insertBook(){ //this method allows the user to insert a new book in the database

    Boolean select = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    File textFile = new File("src/newbooks.txt");
    FileWriter fw = null; //FileWriter and BufferedWriter have to be initialized and used inside a try catch
                          //to be used outside, initialize the objects as null
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try{
        fw = new FileWriter(textFile);//check if it can read the textfile
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);//FileWriter has to be wrapped in BufferedWriter
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("the file could not be found");
        }//end catch

    System.out.println(" select is " +select);//if(text == "n")

    System.out.println("enter the book information below");
    System.out.println("if the informatin is not available, enter\"information not available\"");
    System.out.print("do you wnat to enter a book? ");
    String text = input.next();

    if(text.equals("n"))
            select = true;

    do{

        String book = new String();

        if(select == true)
            break;


        if(text.equals("n")){
            System.out.print("inside if no\n");
            select = true;
            //break;//break here so 
        }
        else if (text.equals("y")){
            System.out.println("inside if y");
            try{

                Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("enter the title of the book: ");
                book = input2.next();
                bw.write(book + ", ");
                System.out.println("after first write");

                System.out.print("enter the author: ");
                book = input2.next();
                bw.write(book + ", ");
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("enter the year of the book: ");
                book = input2.next();
                bw.write(book + ", ");
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("enter the gender: ");
                book = input2.next();
                bw.write(book + ", ");
                //System.out.println();

                System.out.print("enter a description: ");
                book = input2.next();
                bw.write(book + ", ");
                System.out.println();

                bw.write("\n");
                input2.close();
                select = false;
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("the text could not be read");
            }
            input.close();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("you didn't enter a valid selection");
        }


        System.out.print("do you want to enter another booK? Enter y for yes and n for no");
        text = input.nextLine(); //error here
        if(text.equals("n"))
            select = true;

    }while(select == false);//end while select

    //input.close();
}//end of insert method
```

whenever I try to use the Scanner outside the if statements, it gives met the same error. it works if I enter a wrong choice or "n", but if I choose "y" and enter the data the Scanner fails after it gets to the last line for the input inside the do-while loop.

Comment: @BheshGurung Well the question is not bad written, but a bit of research about the exception would probably have quickly resolved the problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
            ...

            bw.write("\n");
            input2.close();
            select = false;
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("the text could not be read");
        }
```

You close the scanner here:

```
        input.close(); // <- remove this line
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("you didn't enter a valid selection");
    }

    ...
```

And here it is already closed.

```
    ...  

    text = input.nextLine();
    if(text.equals("n"))
        select = true;

    ...
```

Close your scanner after you last need it.

This is because you cannot request a new line from a closed scanner.

Read more about it in the API Documentation about scanner:

> **public void close()**
>
> Closes this scanner. If this scanner has not yet
> been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the
> Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked.
> If this scanner is already closed then invoking this method will have
> no effect.
>
> **Attempting to perform search operations after a scanner has been**
> **closed will result in an IllegalStateException.**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()